# Zeeman Effect: How to show that the eigenstates of the unperturbed Hamiltonian are the eigenstates of $J^2$ and $J_z$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics

I'm working on a problem deriving the Zeeman effect. The unperturbed Hamiltonian consists of the Coulomb Hamiltonian plus the spin-orbit interaction Hamiltonian:
$$H^0 = H_{Coulomb} + H_{so} = \frac{P^2}{2m} - \frac{e^2}{r} + \frac{e^2}{2m^2c^2r^3}(J^2 - L^2 - S^2).$$
I have seen from several sources that the simultaneous eigenstates of $J^2$ and $J_z$ are the eigenstates of $H_{Coulomb} + H_{so}$, and these are the states that I need to calculate the perturbation with later on. It is simple to show that the the total angular momentum eigenstates $|JM\rangle$ are eigenstates of $H_{so}$, but it doesn't seem obvious to me that the $|JM\rangle$ are also eigenstates of $H_{Coulomb}$. Is there a simple way of deducing that the eigenstates of $J^2$ and $J_z$ are also the eigenstates of $H_{Coulomb} + H_{so}$?

Answer (score 2):

$\vec{J} = \vec{L}+\vec{S}$, and both $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{S}$ commute with $\vec{P}^2$ and $\vec{r}$: $\vec{L}$ since $\vec{P}^2$ is a scalar and $\vec{r}$ is a purely radial function which is invariant under rotations, and $\vec{S}$ because by definition internal spin is separate from the spatial degrees of freedom.

You can also explicitly check that $[L_i, P_x^2+P_y^2+P_z^2]=[L_i, x^2+y^2+z^2]=0$ for $i=\{x, y, z\}$, using the definition $\vec{L}=\vec{r} \times \vec{p}$ and the commutation relations $[x_i, x_j] = [p_i, p_j] = 0$ and $[x_i, p_j] = i \hbar \delta_{ij}$. This implies $[L_i, f(P_x^2+P_y^2+P_z^2)]=[L_i, g(x^2+y^2+z^2)]=0$ for any differentiable functions $f, g$. Meanwhile $[S_i, P_j] = [S_i, x_j] = 0$ is always true for internal spin.

Comment: If $J^2$, $L^2$ and $S^2$ commute with $H_{Coulomb}$ then we know that these four operators share a common set of eigenstates, but these eigenstates do not necessarily have to be the total angular momentum eigenstates $|JM\rangle$ do they? How do we show that the simultaneous eigenstates of these operators are specifically the total angular momentum eigenstates?

Comment: If you wanted to use those four operators, you would have states like $|j \ell s\rangle$, where $j$ is an eigenvalue associated with $J$, $\ell$ with $L$, and $s$ with $S$. Normally we choose to use $J^2, J_z$ in which case the states are $|J, M\rangle$. Or we could use $L^2, L_z, S^2, S_z$ in which case the states are $|\ell m s m_s\rangle$.

Comment: I think the best way to phrase my question would be to ask how I can explicitly show that the total angular momentum eigenstates $|JM\rangle$ are eigenstates of $H_{Coulomb}$? How would I evaluate the eigenvalue equation etc?

Comment: It's a theorem about operators. If you have two operators $A$ and $B$ such that $[A, B] = 0$ and states $|a\rangle$ satisfying $A|a\rangle = a |a \rangle$, then there is a basis in which $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonal (which means there is a basis of eigenvectors that diagonalize both $A$ and $B$). There's a proof for matrices (which is essentially the same proof as for general operators), eg, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236212/prove-that-simultaneously-diagonalizable-matrices-commute). Given that theorem, just plug in $A=J^2$ or $A=J_z$, and $B=H_{\rm Coulomb}$.

Comment: @Nitram If you wanted to check things in "differential operator" language without trusting the operator stuff, you could start by just focusing on $S=0$, then $J=L$, and the fact that $|\ell, m_\ell\rangle$ are eigenstates of $H_{\rm Coulomb}$ should be straightforward (in the position basis these states are the spherical harmonics, and you can just explicitly check they are eigenstates). Then making $S$ non-zero amounts to replacing the scalar wavefunction with a wavefunction with an index carrying information about the spin. If you tack on this index, the argument is exactly the same.

Comment: @Nitram In a way I think $H_{\rm Coulomb}$ is too trivial an example to be useful. It just doesn't have any part that actually acts on the spin, so the non-zero spin case is exactly the same as zero spin. You might want to look into the Stark effect, which actually cares about spin.